# Android - Java - API - Escape sequence

Tags: android, api, escaping

We working on an Android app which makes an API call to the server.

Below is the expected JSON format of the data.

```
    {"bulk_upload":{"employee":[  {"employeemaster_id":4,"targetdate":"31-12-2015","startdate":"01-01-1990","startvalue":84,"targetvalue":70,"set_by_id":3,            "client_id":"4 "}]}}
```

Below is how we are framing the string in JAVA.

```
 string java= "{\"bulk_upload\":{\"employee\": [{\"id\": \"4 \",\"employeemaster_id\": 4,\"targetdate\": \"11-12-2015\",\"startdate\": \"21-01-2000\",\"startvalue\": 84,\"targetvalue\": 70,\"user_id\": 3,\"set_by_id\": 3}]}}"
```

Somehow, the API is reading it as a string along with the escape sequences.

```
{\"bulk_upload\":{\"employee\": [{\"id\": \"4 \",\"employeemaster_id\": 4,\"targetdate\": \"11-12-2015\",\"startdate\": \"21-01-2000\",\"startvalue\": 84,\"targetvalue\": 70,\"user_id\": 3,\"set_by_id\": 3}]}}
```

We are also setting the header to the request to treat the request as JSON.

Kindly help,
Prawin

Answer (score 0):

I think you must make sure the content send from your server is in the right form.

You can set up a proxy such as [burpsuit](https://portswigger.net/burp/) to intercept your connection and check the content in your proxy. With a proxy you can know whether or not your server's response in the right form.

I think the problem might be that your server send wrong format content.

Comment: Or if you have control of the server, you can just log the content before sending.

Comment: The content is being sent from Android APP.. (Not from Server) The content from the APP is being sent in correct format without those escapes (slashes)

Comment: You mean if there is a proxy between your app and the server, the proxy will get the correct string?